# vue, array/item map in order to flatten into one level per id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue, I'm getting a response from axios that I'm dumping into my console. It looks good in terms of the data, but the data object being returned has multiple rows per item_id because of having different comment types. This is causing me to be unable to use one record per row on the front end.

I need to find the proper way to only have one main level per item_id and have the comments nested in a level under that so that even if a record has 5 different comment/text types it would only be a part of one id response record (i can use comparisons on the front end to show certain comment/text types in certain places).

In my console.log for this.events, I get:

```
0:
  item_id: 12,
  item_text_type: comment,
  item_text: "this has been updated",
  date: "2020/03/03"

1:
  item_id: 12,
  item_text_type: title,
  item_text: "new entry",
  date: "2020/03/03"

2:
  item_id: 13,
  item_text_type: comment,
  item_text: "this has been updated",
  date: "2020/03/03"

3:
  item_id: 13,
  item_text_type: title,
  item_text: "2nd Entry",
  date: "2020/03/03"
```

I'm wanting to get them into a structure more like this:

```
0:
  item_id: 12,
  date: "2020/03/03",
  comments:
    item_text_type: comment,
    item_text: "this has been updated"
    item_text_type: title,
    item_text: "new entry"

0:
  item_id: 13,
  date: "2020/03/03"
  comments:
    item_text_type: comment,
    item_text: "this has been updated"
    item_text_type: title,
    item_text: "2nd entry"
```

So basically, only one record per item_id and compound the comments into a sub-array or something similar to that. Other info (such as date) would be at the id level.

How can I alter this to achieve that result

```
fetchTasks() {
  axios.get('/home')
  .then(response => {
    //handle success

    this.events = response.data.map(({item_comment, ...item}) => ({
      ...item,
      title: item_comment
    }));

    console.log(this.events);

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error)
  })
  .finally(function() {

  })
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Now this includes any other data that accompanies the `item_id` and *comments* related values **however** only the last of any conflicting *extra* data encountered for any particular *item* is preserved.

You also cannot have any extra data named `comments`. If so, it will be discarded.

---

Seems a pretty straight forward data transformation. You'll want to reduce your array to a *map* of some sort (eg plain object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), keyed by the `item_id` property with the *type* and *text* properties added as an object in an array.

From there, you can convert that *map* to the array of objects you want by mapping the keys and values to `item_id` and `comments` respectively.

Something like this

```js
const res = [
  {item_id: 12, item_text_type: 'comment', item_text: "this has been updated", date: '2020/03/03' },
  {item_id: 12, item_text_type: 'title', item_text: "new entry", date: '2020/03/04' },
  {item_id: 13, item_text_type: 'comment', item_text: "this has been updated", date: '2020/03/05' },
  {item_id: 13, item_text_type: 'title', item_text: "2nd entry", date: '2020/03/06' }
]

const dataMap = res.reduce((map, { item_id, item_text_type, item_text, ...extra }) => {
  let { comments, ...item } = map.has(item_id) ? map.get(item_id) : { comments: [] }
  comments.push({ item_text_type, item_text })
  return map.set(item_id, { ...item, ...extra, comments })
}, new Map())
    
const transformed = Array.from(dataMap, ([ item_id, item ]) => ({
  item_id,
  ...item
}))

console.info(transformed)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: none !important; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Perfect, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for here. I"m going to keep playing with this, thank you!

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but I also have trailing dates (see my edit above) and they are not showing in the transformed info. Does any information outside of the comments need to be pushed as well? If I wanted to have each item with ID, date, category and then the comments array, I'm wondering if I'll need to push every value

Comment: Anything else would be at the top level with the ID, only the comments would be in the array. I'm just thinking as I add more to this in the future. I'll edit my question to be safe

Comment: @TomN. This extra requirement significantly changes your question so I suggest you edit that instead of my answer as it's not clear what you now want

Comment: I edited my question. It's not a drastic change, I'm just making sure if anything is added to the parent record and only needs to exist at the id level, how would I implement that

Comment: @TomN. that doesn't really make sense then. How should this handle differing data; what happens if you get the same `item_id` with different `date` (or other non-comment) values?

Comment: It wouldn't in this case, because it's essentially getting one unique record except for the commenyts. One parent record (with Id, date, etc.) has a one to many relationship with comments. The query that returns this data is only returning multiple records per ID due to multiple comment types related to the id. I'm just flattening the comments into an array for each single record

Comment: Don't think about it in terms of what you know your application will deliver. Think in terms of how to process this data; you're iterating over a collection of semi-repeating data... which data should be in the final result where conflicts occur (in this case `date`). The first value for each `item_id`? The last? Something more complex?

Comment: If you're thinking in those terms, then it would be the last value for each item_id (specifically looking at date here)

Comment: Yes that makes sense and it achieves what I expected. I understand why you clarified that though, and I see different ways to tackle this for future changes. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomN. updated again to keep the last conflicting value found